# Using Jquery to grab element inside json array returned by REST API

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am accessing a rest API that is returning some weird JSON.  I'm trying to process it but run into trouble when there's only one.  It's the same API and the same call, just the difference between when one result is returned and multiple results are returned.

I'm trying to use jquery to call the api and then cycle through the results.  I got it working with a single result but then it blew up when I got multiple results.  I changed my code to handle multiple results but then it blows up when there's just one.

JQUERY

```js
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  $.each(item, function(i, it) {
    console.log('it=' + it);
    window.results.push({'Username': it.Username, 'DSN': it.DSN, 'employeeID' : it.employeeID, 'firstName' : it.firstName, 'lastName' : it.lastName, 'fullName' : it.fullName, 'costCenter' : it.costCenter, 'company' : it.company, 'title' : it.title, 'email' : it.email, 'supervisorID' : it.supervisorID, 'supervisorName' : it.supervisorName, 'location' : it.location, 'phone' : it.phone, 'fax' : it.fax, 'pager' : it.pager});
    myIndex++;
  });
});
```

JSON for one result

```
       {"ldapEntry":
{"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"}
    }
```

JSON for multiple results

```
{"ldapEntry":
    [
        {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"},
        {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"Jane Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"},
        {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.smith@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"Jane Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"}
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to use the same code to retrieve the properties of each item return?  Or do I need to write two routines?  And is there an easy way to figure out whether or no there's multiple entries?

Answer (score 0):

You see this a lot when an XML API is converted to JSON without consideration for potential collections.

The best thing you can do is ensure that anything that *could* be an array is **always** treated as an array.

```js
const ldapEntries = Array.isArray(data.ldapEntry)
    ? data.ldapEntry     // it's an array already, nothing else to do
    : [ data.ldapEntry ] // put the single record in an array
window.results.push(...ldapEntries)
myIndex += ldapEntries.length
```

Answer (score -1):

Your multiple results json is not an array, is an object with an array property "ldapEntry"

If you modify it like :

```
[
    {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"},
    {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"Jane Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"},
    {"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.smith@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"Jane Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"}
]
```

it should work!

---

your one result were working because it iterates on objects properties and first property is valid object.

```
[{"Username":"12345","DSN":"","employeeID":"09876","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","fullName":"John Doe","costCenter":"12345","company":"Finance","title":"Expert","email":"john.doe@some.co","supervisorId":"3456","supervisorName":"John Smith","location":"123 Main Street","phone":"555-1212","fax":"555-1212","pager":"1234"}]
```

this will work as well when you modified your schema

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... modify the json.  That's what's being passed back from the REST.  I can't modify it.